# Is the limit of a function in its image set?

Tags: limits, functions

I know it's a kind of basic question, but I couldn't find any answers online.

I have the function:

$\ f(x) = 5 / (x+4)$

I know that:

$\lim_{x \to ∞ } f(x) = 0$

I want to know whether 0 is an element of the image set of f(x).

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is there any number you can plug into $f(x)$ to get $0$? That is, is there a solution to $\frac{5}{x+4} = 0$?

Comment: To see this, you have to solve $$\frac{5}{x+4}=0$$ which has no solution. What can you conclude?

Comment: There is no solution for this formula.

Comment: So 0 is not in the image set? I was confused, because i know that 0.999999 period = 1 and i thought the same would apply to zero.

Comment: rewrite $5/(x+4) = 0$ as $0 \cdot (x+4) = 5$ and get your answer

Comment: It is true that $0.99999\cdots = 1$, but I do not understand how that relates to this problem, or how you expect to get $0$....